# Is there any way to find the amount of time taken by any random task in DAG?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have a requirement of finding the **amount of time** by any particular task in **DAG**.

**For example:**

```
SampleTask=DummyOperator(
    task_id='SampleTask',
    dag=dag)
```

Now I want to know how the time taken by the above task based on its task_id, and in the same way for other tasks as well.

Comment: Im not familiar with subject, but would decorators be a solution?

Comment: Of course **@medvedev1088**'s answer tells you how to do it programmatically, but for a quick visual, `Airflow` Web UI's [Gantt View](https://airflow.apache.org/ui.html#gantt-chart) comes very handy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you go to **Data Profiling > Ad Hoc Query** from the Airflow UI, and select the `airflow_db` database, you can issue this query:

```
select execution_date, duration from task_instance where task_id = 'SampleTask'
```

The `duration` column holds the number of seconds the task ran.

Comment: yeah that works @medvedev1088, can you tell me how to use this inside a current DAG? My requirement is to store the value of the **duration** into a variable inside a DAG. Also this gives me the duration of all the number of times it has run in the past, I want only the duration of present task after completion.

Comment: For this use case I think you can wrap you operator executable into a function that measures start and end time. But it will be a different duration than what's stored in the duration column in the database.

Comment: @nedvedev1088 is there any way/operator to query airflow_db from DAG?

Comment: I’m not sure but even if there is it won’t help because duration is set when task is finished, but you need to access it while the task is running if I understood you correctly

Comment: No I just want in the current DAG, **after completion of the task** @medvedev1088

Comment: There should be a connection called airflow_db. You can use MySqlHook or PostgresHook with conn_id='airflow_db' to access the database.

Comment: yeah you were right, I used MySqlHook, it worked but I am unable to see the result of the query, not even in the log. Can you suggest me something from which I can see the result of the query?

Comment: got it. Few modification in MySqlHook can let us achieve the result we want.

Comment: @AshishKumar Can you share the modifications you made? I am trying to do something similar in postgres

Comment: @Coder this answer might help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54087569/how-to-see-mysqlhook-result-in-log