# How to see MySqlHook result in log

Tags: python-3.x, airflow

I am using **MySqlHook** to establish connection from **airflow_db**, and I am performing some query, but I need to see the result of the query somewhere ( let say log), how can I see?
**Here is the sample code**

```
t1 = MySqlOperator(
    task_id='basic_mysql',
    mysql_conn_id='airflow_db',
    sql="select * from xcom",
    dag=dag)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The MySQL operator currently (airflow 1.10.1 at time of writing) doesn't support returning anything in XCom, so the fix for you, for now, is to write a small operator yourself. You can do this directly in your DAG file:

```
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.operators.mysql_operator import MySqlOperator
from airflow.hooks.mysql_hook import MySqlHook

class ReturningMySqlOperator(MySqlOperator):
    def execute(self, context):
        self.log.info('Executing: %s', self.sql)
        hook = MySqlHook(mysql_conn_id=self.mysql_conn_id,
                         schema=self.database)
        return hook.get_records(
            self.sql,
            parameters=self.parameters)

t1 = ReturningMySqlOperator(
    task_id='basic_mysql',
    mysql_conn_id='airflow_db',
    sql="select * from xcom",
    dag=dag)

def get_records(**kwargs):
    ti = kwargs['ti']
    xcom = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='basic_mysql')
    string_to_print = 'Value in xcom is: {}'.format(xcom)
    # Get data in your logs
    logging.info(string_to_print)

t2 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='records',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=get_records,
    dag=dag)

t1 >> t2
```

Comment: Thanks @kaxil, can't we pull value of xcom without using any operator? Like I created a variable in my DAG, and want to assign xcom to that variable.

Comment: For that use case, you can use Airflow Variable (https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html#variables). And you can set/get the value in the DAG and also use it in templated variable in that operator.

Comment: you mean, I can store xcom value in Airflow Variable?

Comment: **@Ashish Kumar** [`Variable.set(..)`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/models.py#L4560) can be used to persist a `Variable` in `Airflow`'s backend (*meta*) db (even at runtime, i.e., from `Operator`). See its usage [here](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/bin/cli.py#L306)

Comment: I'm trying this but i get an error saying `AttributeError: 'ReturningMySqlOperator' object has no attribute 'mysql_conn_id` version 2.5.1

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, `MySqlOperator` serves the purpose of running an `UPDATE` / `DELETE` etc. query; in other words queries which:

- don't return any result
- return result, but you are not bothered about it

---

In order to get hold of the actual result, you must exploit `MySqlHook`. Here's a small code-snippet (`Python 3.6+`) to get started (not tested, but just for hints)

```
from typing import List, Optional, Any
from airflow.hooks.mysql_hook import MySqlHook

# instantiate a MySqlHook
mysql_hook: MySqlHook = MySqlHook(mysql_conn_id="airflow_db")

# get records (this method comes from airflow.hooks.db_api_hook.DbApiHook)
records: List[List[Optional[Any]]] = mysql_hook.get_records(sql="select * from xcom")

# print records
print(records)

# alternatively, you can write records to task's logger
# note that here 'operator' = reference to your Operator
# operator.log.info("\n".join(records))
```

The output of `print()` / `log.info()` will appear in tasks's log on the UI

Comment: you are right. We need to exploit our MySqlHook, but kaxil showed it in much clear form so marked his answer as correct. Anyway, thanks for contributing.

Comment: just noting that something like `MERGE` / `UPSERT` works perfectly via SQLOperator but still returns valuable Inormation

Answer (score 0):

Generally with Airflow your query should be written such that results go into a temp table (maybe including the `results_name_{{ds_nodash}}`). You can then use the `MySqlTo`*SomethingElse*`Operator` to move the temp table's results. Then clean up by dropping the table.

I don't see any reason that logging the results in Airflow logs would be sufficient work for a DAG to do.